XSLT Variable assigning for each delimiter position from the input XML
In my XSLT I need to assign the values to the variable named FODepartment_LX where X represents the position of the delimiter(+) starting from the leftmost delimiter and Maximum position is 10. If the position of the delimiter doesn't give any value, set the variable is to an empty string ('') for remaininag FODepartment_LX.
Input XML:
<EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
        <ConcatDepartment>+Local_Functions+Group_Functions+Group_Owners+Group_Managers+Group_Leads+Interim_Services</ConcatDepartment>
    </EmpJob>
</EmpJob>

Expected Output in the XSLT so that I can use it for further processing:
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L10" select=""/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L9" select=""/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L8" select=""/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L7" select=""/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L6" select="Interim_Services"/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L5" select="Group_Leads"/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L4" select="Group_Managers"/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L2" select="Group_Owners"/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L2" select="Group_Functions"/>
<xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L1" select="Local_Functions"/>

How can I achieve this in the XSLT?


Variables are part of XSLT, not the result. Ask about your real problem, not your attempted solution - see: https://xyproblem.info/. 2. An instruction like <xsl:variable name="FODepartment_L10" select=""/> will cause an error. 3. Use the tokenize() function.


"In my XSLT I need to assign the values" You're describing your proposed solution, not your problem. Without knowing your problem, it's very hard for us to see whether your proposed solution is a sensible way of tackling it.

If you define a single variable as:
<xsl:variable name="departments" select="tokenize(/EmpJob/EmpJob/ConcatDepartment, '\+')"/>

you can then refer to the individual tokens, for example:
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[2]" />

will return the string "Local_Functions" and:
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[10]" />

will return an empty string.
